# Java Applet Key (apparently) loses focus after firing

Tags: java, swing, applet, focus, keylistener

I have a Java Applet that works totally fine in eclipse, but when I export it to a jar-file, embed it in a HTML and open it with Opera or Firefox, the Key Listener does not work properly. I've tried to extract the appropriate code. The applet is a game, where a player moves forwards while "D" is pressed and stops when they release it:

```
public class World extends JPanel
{
...
public World()
{
...
   seyFocusable(true);
   addKeyBinding();
...
}
private AbstractAction forward = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(!keys.contains(39))
            keys.add(39);
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }
};
private AbstractAction r_forward = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        keys.remove(new Integer(39));
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }
};
 public void addKeyBinding()
{
    int c = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
    InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(c);
    ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "for");
    actionMap.put("for", forward);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "r_for");
    actionMap.put("r_for", r_forward);
}
```

The Applet class does nothing more than "add(new World())". As I said the applet works fine when run in eclipse, but when run it in firefox/opera the player starts running after hitting the "D"-key, then the applet loses focus, while the player keeps running. Sometimes I can force the applet to keep focused with a mouseclick, but even then I cannot stop the player from running. It seems as if the KeyEvent keeps firing.
Also I cannot even get a KeyEvent if I have java console shown (it seems as if the console demands all keyevents) under java preferences, even if I close the console after it pops up.
I tried to use KeyListener instead of KeyBinding with the exact same result.
I also have a Mouselistener which works fine in all of the scenarios.
I'm running on a Mac if that is relevant.

Can I force the applet to not lose input-focus? (why does it lose focus?) Why does the event keep firing? Is it possible to give the applet focus even though the console is shown?

Comment: `JPanel` by itself isn't focusable, so requesting focus on it generally will cause the panel to try and defer focus to the next focusable component it can find.  Try adding `setFocusable(true)` to the `World` classes constructor.

Comment: *"embed it in a HTML"*  Therein lies the problem with focus and applets generally.  Launch it free floating and it will work (or fail) reliably.  But instead: 1) Use a `JFrame` 2) Launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  This will provide a better experience for the end-user. :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer the World class has a setFoccusable(true) command in it.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I had hoped to avoid a floating frame, but maybe that is not a good idea?

Comment: I think it is a *great* idea to use a free floating frame (in case there is any confusion).  The focus problems are solved, and you have better control over size, if the browser is closed the game can continue & many other advantages.  What exactly does the browser wrapper contribute to the game, besides problems?

Comment: How did you go with the suggestion of @MadProgrammer (noting the latest edit)?

Comment: @Andre Thompson: actually I had a setFocusable(true) in the class already. I just forgot to post it here (so it changes nothing). I will try to use a frame (the only problem with a frame is that I had hoped to only have one open window) and JWS and see if that helps. But I still dont understand, why the applet loses focus in the first place and it is really anoying that I cannot even get focus if the console is shown as this narrows my testing possibilities greatly.

Comment: *"I just forgot to post it.."*  As I forgot to mention.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"I still dont understand, why the applet loses focus"*  You might try adding a `FocusListener` and if the focus is lost, call either `pauseGame()` or `requestFocusInWindow()`.  But I recommend you try the frame approach and see if it works for your users.